# Bitcoind Testnet time/timereceived constantly changing?

Tags: bitcoind, timestamp, time, listtransactions

I've got a small question: over a week ago I did some transactions on the Bitcoin testnet as I am developing a new GUI header for full nodes. When continuing development today, I noticed that when running the command 'listtransactions' the fields 'time' and 'timereceived' are different from what they were last week.

When checking the transaction ID on [this website](https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC), it shows the date corresponding with what I receive when using listtransactions.

Can anyone explain to me why the time/timereceived fields changed and why they are so far off from when I actually did the transaction?

Some additional info:

- I started my node on the testnet today for the first time since a
  week
- Actual transaction happened last week on (I think) tuesday
  around 13:00 Amsterdam time

Comment: What are the values for `time` and `timereceived` and what do you think they should be?

Answer (score 0):

"time" is a Unix epoch time when the transaction was added to the wallet

"receivedtime" is A Unix epoch time when the transaction was detected by the local node or the time of the block on the local best blockchain that included the transaction. Not returned to move category payments

Comment: I understand, but why is the time that is being returned by bitcoind different from what it was last week?

Comment: Does your computer time change?

Comment: no, my computer time hasn't changed.

Comment: Could you send TXID?

Comment: 0efb691a93a17ea4253a25a51a081918a73bc09366ae8dfaed6c28098f2eaf02 , on online trackers it also shows the 4th of january. I suppose that the code I use isn't showing earlier transactions for whatever reason. I'll dig into it some further :)